# How to get resolution of an image from image and how to reduce the resolution in percentage with javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

`<img src="assets/img.jpg" id="imgElement" #imageElement  width="50%" height="50%" />`

How to get resolution of an image from image and how to reduce the resolution in percentage with javascript or typescript

My Actual task is to show original image in my site on mouse hover of an element, but while showing that image, because of the higher resolutions image is crossing the browser window, so I want to reduce the percentage of image.

Guys please help me on this.

Comment: To reduce the resolution, render your image in a canvas with a scale of 0.5.

Comment: Issue got resolved by giving max-width for image .